# jqPlot tick doesn't shows correctly

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have data in format [[x1, y1], [x2, y2],..].
x values are from 1 to 31. It respresents days in month.
y values are temperature for these days.

When I plot these data with jqPlot, I get this:
[image]

Here is code:

```
$.post('php/database2json.php', function(data) {
                    var options = {
                        title: 'Месечна температура',
                        series: [
                            { label: 'Ниш'}
                        ],
                        axes:{
                            xaxis:{
                              label:'Дани',
                              labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
                            },
                            yaxis:{
                              label:'Температура',
                              labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
                            }
                        },
                        legend: {
                            show: $legenda
                        },
                        highlighter: {
                          show: $hover  
                        },
                        cursor:{ 
                            show: $zoom, 
                            zoom: $zoom,
false)
                                showTooltip: true
                            }
                        };
                        $('#placeholder').empty();
                        var plot1 = $.jqplot ('placeholder', [data], options);
                    },
                    'json'
                    );
```

How to make short this chart, to fit line?

EDIT: I get json array from post:
[["1","-1"],["2","0"],["3","0"],["4","0"],["5","4"],["6","5"],["7","3"],["8","2"],["9","2"],["10","1"],["11","-2"],["12","-2"],["13","0"],["14","1"],["15","-2"],["16","-1"],["17","-1"],["18","-2"],["19","-1"],["20","3"],["21","-1"],["22","0"],["23","1"],["24","3"],["25","1"],["26","1"],["27","-1"],["28","-1"],["29","4"],["30","5"],["31","5"]]

Comment: Can not help you unless you show your code...

Comment: Indeed, please provide some code examples to allow us to help you.

Comment: @Mark I added some code.

Comment: Exactly what is returned from what is returned from the post?  It looks like you're returning null entries for values all the way up to 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array values are strings.  They should be numeric values.  Modify your PHP script to return numeric (int or float) point pairs.  [Once you do that your plot will scale properly](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/ABmGc/1/):

[image]